# Availability item check

Tags: python, bots

```
import time
import os
import subprocess
from selenium import webdriver

def aval():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("webpage")
    try:
        while True:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath')
            time.sleep(5)
            print("out of stock")
            driver.refresh()
    except:
        print("in stock")
        return True


def speech():
    applescript = """
    display dialog "something in stock" ¬
    with title "This is a pop-up window" ¬
    with icon caution ¬
    buttons {"OK"}
    """

    subprocess.call("osascript -e '{}'".format(applescript), shell=True)

def comp():
    if aval() == True:
        n = 0
        while n != 7:
            os.system("say 'something is in stock'")
            n +=1
        som()
```

I have a problem with identifying whether an item is in stock or not. I used XPath to identify whether the item is in stock or not. The problem is that when I try to input an available item it should refresh the page but instead, it says it is in stock. It works the way I thought but I am not sure why it is says in stock when it just should reload the page. Also, can you please criticize my code? I want to know what you think about it.

Answer (score 0):

There is likely an error with finding the element on the page meaning it executes the except block. You should check your x-path is correct

Comment: Thank you, I'll check